# Get MongoDB operation id from NodeJS native mongodb driver to use for db.killOp

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm looking for a way to give a user a possibility to stop long-running query on MongoDB.
Through UI backed by NodeJS the user requests some data provided by real-time aggregation on MongoDB 3.2. The aggregation can take too much time and I want to enable user to cancel the operation and cancel query execution on MongoDB.

The way to cancel query is known:
`db.killOp(operationId)`

The question is how I can get operation id from nodejs driver for a specific aggregation query. I use the same connection to Mongodb to run all queries on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute admin operations by using [`executeDbAdminCommand`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html#executeDbAdminCommand) command

```
db.executeDbAdminCommand({"killOp":1}, {"op": operationId})
```

If `operationId` in unknown, you can list all operations by using [`currentOp`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/#db.currentOp) to retrieve current or all operations

Comment: I have 10 users who run aggregations simultaneously. User X presses "Cancel" and I need to cancel this user's aggregation query. What operation id should I use for killOp? Also, all the users have the same aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Oh, that's a completely different problem that is not even related to nodejs.

Comment: I suggest you create another question with this specific domain. This question suggests that your problem is with the node.js and mondodb driver, which seems not to be true OR is a problem in the future, once you solve this other issue

Comment: If nodejs driver can return anyhow operation id when I issue db.collection('X').aggregate(pipeline. cb), I'm ok.

Answer (score 0):

Use `db.currentOp()` command to list every operation currently in progress
https://blog.serverdensity.com/mongodb-monitoring-current-operations/

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.